# how can i save text into pdf?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pypdf

i can display the file on my text widget, and i have to save the file into pdf when i click btn save, but i don't know how to save file from text widget into pdf.

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

window = Tk()

def btnbrowse():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    path.set(filename)
    get_info(filename)

def get_info(path):

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
        info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
        page = pdf.getPage(0)

        judul.set(info.title)
        penulis.set(info.author)
        keyword.set(info.subject)
        txt.insert(INSERT, page.extractText())

#membuat label
l1 = Label(window, text = "Judul")
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
l1 = Label(window, text = "Penulis")
l1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
l1 = Label(window, text = "Keyword")
l1.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
l1 = Label(window, text = "Abstract")
l1.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
l1 = Label(window, text = "Category")
l1.grid(row = 6, column = 0)

#membuat Entries
path = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable = path, width = 100)
e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
judul = StringVar()
ejdl = Entry(window, textvariable = judul, width = 100)
ejdl.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
penulis = StringVar()
epnls = Entry(window, textvariable = penulis, width = 100)
epnls.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
keyword = StringVar()
ekw = Entry(window, textvariable = keyword, width = 100)
ekw.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
txt = Text(window, height = 5)
txt.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

#membuat combobox
cb = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 100)
cb['values'] = ("Computer Graphics & Design",
                "Computer System",
                "Data Science",
                "Human Computer Interaction",
                "Information Security")
cb.grid(row = 6, column = 1)


#membuat button
btn = Button(window, text = "Choose a File", width = 12, command = btnbrowse)
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

btn = Button(window, text = "Save", width = 12)
btn.grid(row = 7, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

is it possible to save file on text widget into pdf?

if it's possible to save file into pdf, how can i save the file into pdf?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches for generating PDF in python. pdfkit is one of the better approaches as, it renders HTML into PDF with various image formats, HTML forms, and other complex printable documents.
Install pdfkit: You can install it with pip using the following command.

```
pip install pdfkit
```

After install you can generate pdf file from a url or from a file,
For example for you to save a .txt file to a pdf file, you can use this(untested):

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file('textfile.txt', 'textfile.pdf')
```

Or you can you open and read you text file and store it in a variable then write it as a string to pdf file(I tested this way and it worked):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read() #store .txt file in data 
pdfkit.from_string(data, 'data.pdf')#write data in pdf file
```

Comment: can i use that methot to save file from text widget? i mean i have to save file into pdf from text widget, not only convert the file to pdf